# How do I do a type cast in Laravel Fluent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, fluent

How can I do a type cast for comparing values in Laravel Fluent? For example if I have the following MySQL:

```
SELECT * from table1 WHERE  CAST(`values` AS SIGNED) > $myVar
```

This is what I currently have after writing the above in Fluent:

```
$query = DB::connection('mysql')->table('table1')
    ->where('values', '>', $myVar);
```

Currently the database is treating this as a string. The column in the table needs to be kept as a varchar for other reasons. How can I do the type cast for this particular query in Laravel Fluent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Untested, but I believe this should work:

```
$query = DB::connection('mysql')->table('table1')
    ->where(DB::raw('CAST(values AS SIGNED)'), '>', $myVar);
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. I guess it has to be written in raw?

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
$query= DB::connection('mysql')
            ->table('table1')
            ->whereRaw('CAST(values AS SIGNED) > '.$myVar);
```

works